# Flutter doesn't recognize it's own widget named parameters after updating

Tags: flutter, dart, undefined, flutter-dependencies, beta

I was developing a project on my laptop and moved to my desktop, so I got some errors. I updated flutter and after that, I get this warning:

```
    for (Offset center in scaleHandles) {
      handles.add(Rect.fromCircle(center: center, radius: r));
    }
```

"The named parameter 'center' isn't defined.
Try correcting the name to an existing named parameter's name, or defining a named parameter with the name 'center'.dartundefined_named_parameter" When I hover over "fromCircle" I get this tip "Rect Rect.fromCircle({dynamic Offset})". That doesn't make any sense! The official docs also state that a Rect from a circle takes CENTER and RADIUS. What's going on????

- This is my flutter version:
  G:>flutter doctor --version
  Flutter 1.19.0-4.3.pre • channel beta • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
  Framework • revision 8fe7655ed2 (3 weeks ago) • 2020-07-01 14:31:18 -0700
  Engine • revision 9a28c3bcf4
  Tools • Dart 2.9.0 (build 2.9.0-14.1.beta)
- Before I updated to flutter beta, this is the error I got:
  Running "flutter pub get" in spirals_app...
  Because every version of flutter_test from sdk depends on path 1.6.4 and spirals_app depends on path ^1.7.0, flutter_test from sdk is forbidden.
  So, because spirals_app depends on flutter_test any from sdk, version solving failed.
  pub get failed (1; So, because spirals_app depends on flutter_test any from sdk, version solving failed.)
  exit code 1

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L2Chs.png)

Comment: just do invalidate caches and restart

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You will just need to run in your terminal the following commands

```
flutter clean
flutter pub get
```

and then you may need to restart your editor

Comment: It worked! Thank you! It just had never happened before so I got a little desperate and forgot to even try that...